# CheckBox event not triggered in mobile browser but works OK on desktop

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having some trouble with Checkboxes click event on my mobile device browser.

The following codes work fine on desktop browser. I can see the text shown on the TempPage once the Checkbox ic clicked.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Check Box click event
    $(".checkboxclass").bind ("click", function (event)
        {
          var tempstring ='<p> CHECKBOX Click works </p>'
          $('.class-TempPage').append(tempstring);
        });
    }
</script>
<!-- ########### -->
<!-- TEMP page -->
<!-- ########### -->
<div data-role="page" id="id-TempPage">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div class="class-TempPage">
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- ########### -->
<!-- CHECKBOX page -->
<!-- ########### -->

<div data-role="page" id="id-CheckBoxPage">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div class="class-CheckBoxPage">
                <ul id="dataPointList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox-4"  />
                            <label class="checkboxclass" for="checkbox-4" data-iconpos="right">blah4</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

However, when I run it on my mobile phone's broswer (Dolphin for eg) it doesn't work.

Why is that so? How to get round this?

This link -- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html -- mention something, not sure if relevant.

Thanks.